# Monitor transport,network and link layer buffers/queue (loaded, empty, full and drop) in Linux

Tags: linux, udp

As far as i know, these are buffer/queues for UDP in Linux (correct me if im wrong)

UDP Tx : [sendto] UDP socket buffer(getsockopt(SO_SNDBUF))  ->  interface socket buf()   -> driver ring buffer
UDP_Rx : driver ring buffer   -> backlog queue    ->  [recvfrom] UDP socket buffer(getsockopt(SO_RCVBUF))

I know we can monitor drop/queue:
        -socket buffer(UDP) at /proc/net/udp
        -interface queue(IP) at /proc/net/dev

Where can i monitor the driver queue/buffer(MAC) for a drop in Linux?

p/s: i wanna see and PROVE what happen to the datagramme in those queues if we cut the connection during UDP transfer over WLAN.

Comment: i ask this question differently here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500428/linux-udp-packet-is-kept-in-buffer-or-droped-when-network-is-unreacheable-ho

Comment: I found the solution on how I can observe what happen to those packets by using FTRACE. Now i can prove what happen to those packets in each layer by reading the LXR of the function called.

Answer (score 0):

use $tc -s -d qdisc ls dev eth0 for eth0 interface